# Accessing file from host system in Docker

Tags: docker, file

I want to use graph-tools to manage some data, however, i am unable to install the package on my ubuntu 18.04.

So i downloaded the docker file from the official site, and i was wondering how to access my .csv files on the host system from docker.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a volume for that:

```
docker run -v <path_to_your_files>:<path_inside_container> ...
```